# error when I try to read a ros msg composite by another msg file into a node subscriber calback

Tags: ros, shared-ptr, message, callbacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Error when I try to read a ros msg composite by another msg file into a node subscriber callback.

I have this ROS msgs.

```
WalkingRequest.msg
uint32 mode  #/**< The walking mode. */
Pose2D speed 
Pose2D target 

Pose2D.msg
float32 theta
float32 x
float32 y
```

Within the callback of my suscriber node I use:

```
void myCallBack(const naoros1::WalkRequest::ConstPtr& walkRequest_)
{
    walkRequest.mode = walkRequest_->mode;
```

Which works fine. But when I try to access to the embedded Pose2D msg like that:

```
walkRequest.speed.x = walkRequest_->speed->x;
```

I have this error:

```
   /home/nao/ros-nao/workspace_nao/sandbox/naoros1/src/src/UChProcess/UChCognitionExecutor.cpp: In member function ‘void UChCognitionExecutor::runModules(const boost::shared_ptr<const naoros1::WalkRequest_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’:
    /home/nao/ros-nao/workspace_nao/sandbox/naoros1/src/src/UChProcess/UChCognitionExecutor.cpp:47: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘const naoros1::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> >’
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47377/error-when-i-try-to-read-a-ros-msg-composite-by-another-msg-file-into-a-node-subscriber-calback/) by [LeonardoLeottau](https://answers.ros.org/users/3140/leonardoleottau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2012-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`walkRequest_` is a pointer type, `walkRequest_->speed` is a value type, so you want:

```
walkRequest.speed.x = walkRequest_->speed.x;
```

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1